# Unity-how to divide/ slice one plane to 2by2 ..3by3..4by4.. and so one and make each tile an instance

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a chord playing box.

[image: rough image that i drew]

In a box (square) there will be one or more balls.

The square have normally 6 sides. On each side, I want to interactively divide it by 2by2 3by3 and so on..

For example, if i make one side by 2*2 plane, my 'tiles' will be total 24.

I call the divided rects, 'tile'. if the ball collides to a tile, then some music note plays off. Which means my tiles will be buttons to playing notes.

I used processing, and since I heard that Unity has good physics engine I tried doing my project with Unity. So I am new to Unity and C# but I do understand some programming languages.

My question is, How can I interactively divide planes in real time by putting in some input and make it as an instance, so that it can work as a independent button?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use 6 planes (with colliders) for the six sides of your box.
Then you can use unity's `Collider.OnCollisionEnter(Collision)` method to detect the collision and get the `ContactPoint` where a ball touched the plane.
[Unity documentation - OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)

This point can then be converted to the hit plane's local space using `Transform.InverseTransformPoint`. What you get is a kind of a normalized point (aka it is affected by the plane scale). Depending on the pivot of your plane you'll have to perform a translation for your x and y values to be between 0 and 1 (e.g. -0.5 on both axes, if you have a centered pivot).

Using these normalized coordinates you can "divide" your plane logically (e.g. a hit point between 0 and 0.5 on x and 0 and 0.5 on y wouldbe quadrant 0) . This saves you the pain of having to deal with multiple objects per box side which have to be seemlessly aligned etcpp.